# Why Do I Get Multiple Print Line Results - Xcode Console

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code that 're-jigs' the height of various table view cells.

I am confused as to why I receive multiple print statements in the Xcode console as follows:

[image]

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

if (!defaults.boolForKey("purchased")) {

        print("show banner, reduce filmstrip");
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: height = 4
        case 2: height = 70
        default: height = tableView.frame.size.height - 219
        }
        return height }

    else {
        print("hide banner, increase filmstrip");
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: height = 4
        case 2: height = 70
        default: height = tableView.frame.size.height - 169
        }
        return height
    }
}
```

How can I amend my `print("")` statement to achieve only **one (1)** print line output in the XCode console?

Comment: This gets printed every time a cell gets dequeued. If you really want to show only 1 printed statement you could use dispatch_once() or create your own class which prints messages, and groups the same messages.

Comment: I see. I will amend accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called as many rows as you have in your table (what you return in `numberOfRowsInSection` , each time with a different `indexPath`, probably before you save a value for key "purchased"

Comment: Understand the logic now. Thanks. Have amended with kind comment of @Sandeer Salmons (above) to include `dispatch_once()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

With the kind directions given by @Sandeer Salmons and @oren, I have amended my code to:

```
struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        print("show banner, reduce filmstrip");
        }
```

Now I get my desired one (1) line print result in the console.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: There's a much simpler solution to this. Move the print statement to `viewDidLoad` or some other method that isn't called over and over.